# How to store images for not existing entities in database?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Let's say I have table `entities` with `id` and `title`.

And I want to attach images to these entities using this table

```
images:
    id - primary key of image
    filename - path to image on local filesystem
entity_images
    id_entity - foreign key to `entities.id`
    id_image - foreign key to `images.id`
```

The problem is: images must be added during creation of entities (user sees form, where he types `title` and selectes images)

Solution, which I use: upload images via ajax and then during creation pass only ids of these images (there can be a lot of them, so doing this through single `POST` request is not the best idea)

Problem 1: what if user does not create entity after uploading image?

Problem 2: during image upload I create different versions of image(big, medium and small). And when it's done, I create record in database. But what if something goes wrong? Record is written to database, but filesystem cache is not written yet. There is record in database, but no file on disk. Or file is written but database record can not be created due some reason. What are solution for this problem? May be there is something like transaction for this?

Comment: Why create anything in the database? Upload the files in the background, stored the pathes in session. Once the entity is finalised, then you can create the entries in the db. The rest is generic error handling. Pls do not ask multiple questions in a single post. It is a lot more difficult to answer them.

Comment: you could upload images upon form submit rather than ajax, in which case you only have problem 2, which will always exists and for that you have to do generic error handling as @Shadow suggests, i.e. check for existence of files on disk before displaying entities, perhaps a reporting/logging feature for entities found without images. Problem 2 should be  a very rare if ever occurrence, if everything which needs to back this process is indeed in place.

Comment: But what if user leaves session? There will be orphaned file.

Comment: You can create and register your own session destroy and garbage collect funxtions amd remove those orphaned files. Or use a scheduled job to do this cleanup on a regular basis.